# Ruby Base58 for Waves platform

Tags: ruby, base58

I want to implement [Wavesplatform](https://wavesplatform.com) wrapper on ruby for my project.
I'm stuck right in the beginning, trying to implement example from [Docs](https://github.com/wavesplatform/Waves/wiki/Cryptographic-practical-details#example) with Base58 and Bitcoin alphabet.

> The string "teststring" are coded into the bytes [5, 83, 9, -20, 82,
>   -65, 120, -11]. The bytes [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] are coded into the string "7bWpTW".

I use [BaseX gem](https://github.com/brianhempel/base_x)

```
num = BaseX.string_to_integer("7bWpTW", numerals: "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz")
puts bytes = [num].pack("i").inspect

=> "\x05\x04\x03\x02"
```

The output somewhat similar to [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] bytes array from example, but I'm not really sure how to properly manipulate bytes.

Comment: What `BaseX::Base58.string_to_integer("7bWpTW")` returns?

Comment: @mudasobwa 4328719365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pack`/`unpack` won’t much help here: the size is undetermined and the integer you get might contain (and in most cases contains) many bytes. One should code a bit here:

```
byte_calculator = ->(input, acc = []) do
  rem, val = input.divmod(256)
  acc << (val > 128 ? val - 256 : val)
  rem <= 0 ? acc : byte_calculator.(rem, acc)
end

byte_calculator.
  (BaseX::Base58.string_to_integer("teststring")).
  reverse
#⇒ [
#  [0] 5,
#  [1] 83,
#  [2] 9,
#  [3] -20,
#  [4] 82,
#  [5] -65,
#  [6] 120,
#  [7] -11
# ]
```

The same way one should operate with the reverse conversion:

```
BaseX::Base58.integer_to_string([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
      reverse.
      each_with_index.
      reduce(0) do |acc, (e, idx)| 
  acc + e * (256 ** idx)
end)
#⇒ "7bWpTW"
```